# cx_Freeze error on target compter

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyside, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I wrote a GUI program using Python (3.3) and PySide (1.2.1). I cx_Freezed it and moved the build folder to the target computer (being Windows 7 64bit). When I try to run my program, I get this error:

[image]

I researched and found that someone else had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949738/python-3-3-cxfreeze-pyside-error/17950330) similar to this, but the answer said that this issue would be fixed in PySide version 1.2.1.

I guess not?? Or am I doing something wrong.